# NCURSES SW runs in lxterminal, but doesn't run in a native Linux terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, c, ncurses, lxterminal

I wrote a "complex" C program using the `ncurses` library. It "correctly" runs in a `lxterminal` or `gnome-terminal` session; but doesn't run in a "native Linux terminal" session without X started *(obtained both restarting the PC without X or using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd> terminal).*

The problem is that in the "native Linux session" the program doesn't display any windows, it displays only one of the text printed in the third generated window.

- I saw that in gnome-terminal the `TERM` environment variable is set as `xterm-256color`. In contrast, the native Linux terminal has `TERM` set as `linux`.
- Then I set `TERM` in the native Linux terminal using:

  ```bsh
  export TERM=xterm-256color
  ```

  When I set `TERM` as `xterm-256color` the program runs better and displays an usable interface, but all the chars to construct boxes are substituted by other chars, the vertical line char is substituted by the `x`char.
- But I thought `xterm` is for X terminal section then I tried `ansi`:

  ```bsh
  export TERM=ansi
  ```

  With this last setting, the program displays almost nothing as in the case of the native setting.
- Using `vt100`:

  ```bsh
  export TERM=vt100
  ```

  The programs runs better, but is displayed in B/W.

The same behaviour happens also with the examples released with the ncurses library.

Have you some explanation?

How do I set the terminal capability in a way I may correctly start my ncurses program?

It's possible that I've not set something relevant to terminal (or relevan to ncurses) in the code?

**Example**

```
#include <ncurses.h>

static void initGeneralScreen(void);

int main()
{
    WINDOW * deskW, * msgW, * otherW;

    initGeneralScreen();

    deskW = newwin(21,80,0,0);
    wbkgd(deskW, COLOR_PAIR(3));
    box(deskW, 0, 0 ); // sets default borders for the window
    wrefresh( deskW ); // update the terminal screen

    msgW = newwin(3, 80, 21, 0);
    wbkgd(msgW, COLOR_PAIR(1));
    box(msgW, 0, 0 ); // sets default borders for the window
    wrefresh(msgW ); // update the terminal screen

    otherW = newwin(1,78,0,1);
    wbkgd(otherW, COLOR_PAIR(1));
    wrefresh(otherW ); // update the terminal screen

    mvwprintw(msgW,1,1,"Test ... <Hit a key to exit>");
    wrefresh(msgW ); // update the terminal screen

    mvwprintw(otherW,0,0,"Test1");
    wrefresh(otherW ); // update the terminal screen

    wgetch(deskW);

    delwin( otherW );
    delwin( msgW );
    delwin( deskW );
    endwin();

    return 0;
}

void initGeneralScreen(void)
{
    initscr();  // initialize Ncurses
    noecho();   // disable echoing of characters on the screen
    raw();      //
    keypad(stdscr,TRUE);

    start_color();

    init_pair(1,COLOR_YELLOW | 8, COLOR_BLUE);
    init_pair(2,COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLUE);
    init_pair(3,COLOR_WHITE | 8, COLOR_BLACK | 8);
}
```

**Notes:**

- Kernel

  ```
  Linux 4.15.0-101-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 11 10:07:26 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```
- `libncurses.so.5.9`

Comment: I'd like who down-votes the question give some explanations, too. It's not clear and not useful a down-votes without explanations.

Comment: Although that is true, please note that [cross-posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61896568/ncurses-sw-runs-in-lxterminal-but-doesnt-run-in-a-native-linux-terminal) is strongly discouraged, and that you should decide for either of the sites for posting your question, deleting the duplicate(s) on the other one(s).

Comment: Can you create some minimal example, which will show the problem? May be a little program that draws a window and works in a pseudo-terminal and doesn't work in the virtual terminal (`tty`). In other words, you should shrink your complex program until you find out the cause of the problem. Then add the relevant code into the question.

Comment: @MiniMax ... Example done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed

```
init_pair(1,COLOR_YELLOW | 8, COLOR_BLUE);
init_pair(2,COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLUE);
init_pair(3,COLOR_WHITE | 8, COLOR_BLACK | 8);
```

to

```
init_pair(1,COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLUE);
init_pair(2,COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLUE);
init_pair(3,COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLACK);
```

and program began to work as expected.

The problem has appeared because you use colors for background (by `wbkgd` function), which **Linux virtual terminal** is not supporting. It supports only 8 colors for background and 8 for foreground - [About ncurses Colors](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/about-ncurses-colors-0) .

**See:**

```
printf("COLOR_YELLOW\t\t%d\n", COLOR_YELLOW);
printf("COLOR_BLUE\t\t%d\n", COLOR_BLUE);
printf("COLOR_BLACK\t\t%d\n", COLOR_BLACK);
printf("COLOR_WHITE\t\t%d\n", COLOR_WHITE);
puts("");
printf("COLOR_YELLOW | 8\t%d\n", COLOR_YELLOW | 8);
printf("COLOR_BLACK | 8\t\t%d\n", COLOR_BLACK | 8);
printf("COLOR_WHITE | 8\t\t%d\n", COLOR_WHITE | 8);
```

**Output**

```
COLOR_YELLOW        3
COLOR_BLUE          4
COLOR_BLACK         0
COLOR_WHITE         7

COLOR_YELLOW | 8    11    // not allowed for background
COLOR_BLACK | 8     8     // not allowed for background
COLOR_WHITE | 8     15    // not allowed for background
```

---

#### EDIT

**1.**

According to [init_pair signature](https://linux.die.net/man/3/init_pair):

```
int init_pair(short pair, short f, short b);
```

the second argument is for foreground, the third is for background, so the only third argument in the color pair `3` should be changed from `COLOR_BLACK | 8` to simple `COLOR_BLACK` in your example.

Thus, this is legitimate in the Linux console:

```
init_pair(1,COLOR_YELLOW | 8, COLOR_BLUE);
init_pair(2,COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLUE);
init_pair(3,COLOR_WHITE | 8, COLOR_BLACK);
```

This is answering why you don't see much color changes when set `TERM=xterm-256color` in the console. Because only `COLOR_BLACK | 8` isn't supported, others are fine. And `COLOR_BLACK | 8` isn't working as expected - the body of table is in plain black, unlike of **gnome-terminal**, where it is colored by grey. So, **the colors are not completely correct**, as you wrote in the comment.

**2. Why in gnome-terminal the behaviour is different?**

Because **gnome-terminal** and **Linux console** are two terminal emulators, which use different sets of escape sequences. Think about them as two different hardware terminals from different vendors.

- [xterm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm)  is the standard terminal emulator for the X Window System.
- **gnome-terminal** is the `xterm` compliant terminal emulator.
- **Linux console** is **VT102** emulator resided in the kernel. Not a strict one, for example **VT102** didn't have colors.

It is why `ncurses` library is needed - to write terminal independent applications. The set of each terminal emulator capabilities are stored in the `terminfo` database. **Linux console** has own entry, as well as **gnome-terminal**. `ncurses` uses information from this database to manage terminal emulators.

You can compare entries by this command:

```
infocmp -c linux xterm-256color
```

So, when you change the `TERM` variable from `linux` to `xterm-256color` in the Linux console, you say `ncurses` to use foreign set of escape sequences for communication with terminal instead of authentic (right) one. Some codes can be understandable despite of this, because they have similarities, but not all.

**Related links:**

- [TERM, terminfo, termcap. What are they how does Emacs use it?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/26774/28828)
- [termcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap)
- [terminfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo)
- [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library))

Comment: Why in gnome-terminal the behaviour is different (it's graphic, I know)? but ... Why is the characters output wrong if I set TERM=xterm-256color, but the color are correct? How I may set the correct charset and terminal type to obtain my expected result?

Comment: @SirJoBlack See edit.

Comment: I'm trying to manipulate term configuration ... I'd like to find a solution to use all color ... Using ansi code I've all color I want ... then I think that manipulating I may obtain the same behaviour.